# Undefined class error when template class member uses class itself as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

The code excerpt below is a minimal working example of an issue that I am struggling to understand involving C++ templates. As it is, the code compiles fine. If the lines outside of the `main` function that are commented out are commented back in, I receive the following compilation error relating to line 73 i.e. `C<A> c(A<C<A>>(3.0));`:

```
testing.cpp(61): error C2079: 'C<A>::b_' uses undefined class 'A<C<A>>'
testing.cpp(10): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'C<A>' being compiled
testing.cpp(73): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<C<A>>' being compiled
```

Line 69 i.e. `C<A> c(A<C<A>::this_class>(3.0));` compiles in all cases.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class Z>
class A {

public:
    // typedef typename Z::traits_type Traits;

    A(double data = 2.0) : data_(data) { 
        cout << "Constructing A with data: " << data_ << endl;
    }

    double data() const {
        return data_;
    }

    void setup(Z* z) {
        z_ = z;
    }

    void doStuff() const {
        // cout << "A's foo: " << Traits::foo() << endl;
        cout << "Instance of Z's data_: " << z_->data_ << endl;
    }

private:
    double data_;
    Z* z_;

};

//struct CTraits {
//    static int foo() {
//        return 1;
//    }
//};

template<template <class> class B = A>
class C {

public:
    typedef C<B> this_class;
    // typedef CTraits traits_type;

    C(const B<this_class>& b = B<this_class>()) : data_(4.0), b_(b) { 
        cout << "Constructing C using B with data: " << b_.data() << endl;
        b_.setup(this);
    }

    void doStuff() const {
        b_.doStuff();
    }

private:
    double data_;

    friend class B<this_class>;
    B<this_class> b_;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // The following line compiles regardless of whether all lines above that 
    // are commented are commented in or out.
    // C<A> c(A<C<A>::this_class>(3.0));

    // This will not compile if the lines above, outside of main, that are commented 
    // out are commented back in.
    C<A> c(A<C<A>>(3.0));

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why does the line `C<A> c(A<C<A>>(3.0));` cause a compilation error when the commented out lines above it, outside of `main`, are commented back in? In other words, what changes to cause the compilation to fail?

Additionally, why does the line `C<A> c(A<C<A>::this_class>(3.0));` compile when `C<A> c(A<C<A>>(3.0));` does not? In other words, what is special about using `C<A>::this_class` as the template parameter to `A` over just using `C<A>`?

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using? This compiles fine for me, even with the commented out lines added back in. It works in 19.14 and above, but breaks in the older 19.10 for ARM

Comment: I'm using the latest ms142 with `ISO C++17` enabled and I get the error:`C2079:  'C<A>::b_' uses undefined class 'A<C<A>>'` It stems from the first `typedef typename Z::traits_type Traits;` in class A

Comment: Interesting --- I find that this compile error shows up when I use clang++ v6.0.1, but not when I use g++ v7.4.0.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio version 15.9.15 with compiler version 19.16.27032.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue using `clang++`.

Let's start with a simpler example. Keep the class definitions you have, but instead use the following `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A<C<A>> x(3.0);
}
```

This fails to compile---let's work out why (informally).

The compiler has to instantiate the class `A<C<A>>`. To do that, it plugs `C<A>` into `A` as the template parameter `Z`. Then it sees the line `typedef typename Z::traits_type Traits`, which requires it to instantiate `Z`, which is `C<A>`. When instantiating `C<A>`, it sets the template parameter `B` to `A`, so when it sees `B<this_class> b_` it has to instantiate `A<C<A>>`. But this is the same class we were trying to instantiate at the beginning! This is why the compiler gives an error---it has an "incomplete type" because the compiler realizes it has started instantiating that type already, but hasn't finished yet.

This is the same reason why you get an error if you define:

```
class D {
    D x;
};
```

Now for the second part of your question: why does using `this_class` fix the problem?
To understand that, consider this simpler example (again with the same class definitions as before):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    typedef C<A>::traits_type y;
    A<C<A>> x(3.0);
}
```

What's happening here is that the `typedef` statement requires the compiler to instantiate `C<A>` early. In doing so, it encouters the `b_` variable as before and tries to instantiate `A<C<A>>`, which once again plugs `C<A>` into `A` as the template parameter `Z`. Then it sees the line `typedef typename Z::traits_type Traits`, but at this point it has already evaluated the `typedef CTraits traits_type` for `C<A>` and therefore continues without trying to instantiate `C<A>` again.

## Causes

To summarize the above discussion, there are two causes for the behavior you're seeing. First, even though you just need `C<A>::traits_type` the compiler will try to instantiate the entire `C<A>`. Second, the compiler is OK with incomplete types when accessing `C<A>::traits_type` (`Z<A>::traits_type`), but not when instantiating the type itself as in `A<C<A>> b_` (`B<this_type> b_`).

The reason why `C<A> c(A<C<A>::this_class>(3.0));` works is that `C<A>::this_class` forces the compiler to instantiate `C<A>` early.

## Workaround

One possible workaround for you is to explicitly instantiate the template you need ahead of time, to prevent the loop:

```
template class C<A>;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    C<A> c(A<C<A>>(3.0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam for the detailed answer, this gives me a good understanding of what I was seeing.